# How can I rank a cell in a column in Pandas every 5 rows?

Tags: pandas

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [10, 8, 4, 3, 5, 1, 21, 14, 19, 20, 7, 6, 0, 4, 3, 11]})

     a
0   10
1    8
2    4
3    3
4    5
5    1
6   21
7   14
8   19
9   20
10   7
11   6
12   0
13   4
14   3
15  11
```

should be: nan, nan, nan, nan, 3, 1, 5, 4, ...

I tried:
`df['rank'] = df['a'][-5:].rank()`

It did not give the expected output. Is there a way to do this in an efficient way to deal with big amount of rows?

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: I mean, for each cell in the column 'a', I want to compare its value with 4 rows above it, which is to find the rank of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`rankdata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rankdata.html) function:

```
from scipy.stats import rankdata

df.rolling(5).apply(lambda x: rankdata(x)[-1])
```

Output:

```
      a
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   3.0
5   1.0
6   5.0
7   4.0
...
```